# bootstrap 3 single page design using # to call content up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, singlepage

I am using # to call content to the top of my single page website design, however, with a fixed top navbar at 60px height, the top 60px of the div which I call to the top is covered by my navbar.

Any suggestions on how I can work around or avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a 60px margin to your body...

```css
body {
    margin-top:60px;
}
```